# how to fix in this case? syntax error: missing ';' before '* "node"?

Tags: c++, syntax

I looked through other questions asked similarly and can not seem to find a relatable cause  here is what I think is the relevant code:(EDIT: including all code at request)

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pitri.h"


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

Pitri.cpp

```
#include "Pitri.h"
#include "node.h"
#include "dood.h"
//#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


Pitri::Pitri()
{
    this->length = 0;
    this->head = NULL;
}


Pitri::~Pitri()
{
}

void Pitri::add(dood data)
{
    node* nnode = new node();
    nnode->data = data;
    nnode->next = this->head;
    this->head = nnode;
    this->length++;
}

void Pitri::remove(node * t, node* p)
{
    if (this->head == t)
    {
        if (t->next == NULL)
            this->head = NULL;
        else
            this->head = t->next;
        t->data.Death();
        free(t);
    }
    else
    {
        if (t->next == NULL)
            p->next = NULL;
        else
            p->next = t->next;
        t->data.Death();
        free(t);
    }
}

void Pitri::printP()
{
    int tallyBr = 0;
    node* head = this->head;
    int i = 1;
    while (head)
    {

    }
}

void Pitri::printS()
{
}

void Pitri::printBL()
{
}

void Pitri::populate(int x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        dood* baby = new dood;
        this->add(baby);
    }

}

void Pitri::cycle(int x)
{
    //Initial definition in the event that the head node reproduces
    node* curr = this->head;
    node* mate = this->head->next;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int deaths = 0;
        int births = 0;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Pitri has gone extinct!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        while (curr)
        {
            if (rand() % 100 + 1 <= this->mort && this->mort)
            {
                deaths++;
                remove(curr);
            }
            else if (curr->data.GetAge() == this->ttl && this->ttl)
            {
                deaths++;
                remove(curr);
            }
            else if (rand() % 100 + 1 <= this->birth && this->birth)
            {
                births++;
                add(curr->data.Reproduce(mate->data));
            }
            if (curr->next == NULL)
                break;
            mate = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

}
```

Pitri.h

```
    #pragma once


class Pitri
{
public:
    Pitri();
    ~Pitri();
    int length;
    node *head;

    void add(dood data);
    void remove(node* t);
    void printP();
    void printS();
    void printBL();
    void populate(int);
    void cycle(int);
    int getBB();
    int getBL();
    int getLL();

private:
    int ttl,mort,birth;

};
```

dood.cpp

```
    #include "dood.h"
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

bool dood::init = false;

dood::dood()
{
    if (!init)
    {
        //Set time for random seed
        srand(time(0));
        init = true;
    }

    Primary = rand()%2;
    //Set Blue eyes to always have Blue recessive.
    if (Primary == 0)
        Secondary = rand()%2;
    else
        Secondary = 1;
}

dood::dood(int a, int b)
{
    if (!init)
    {
        //Set time for random seed
        srand(time(0));
        init = true;
    }

    Primary = a;
    Secondary = b;

}


dood::~dood()
{
}

void dood::Mutate()
{


    this->Primary = rand()%2;
    //Set Blue eyes to always have Blue recessive.
    if (Primary == 0)
        Secondary = rand()%2;
    else
        Secondary = 1;
}

dood dood::Reproduce(dood donor)
{
    int dPri = donor.GetPrimary();
    int dSec = donor.GetSecondary();
    int bPri, bSec;

    int punitvalue = rand() % 4 + 1;

    //if at least one dood has Brown/Brown...
    if((Primary == 0 && Secondary == 0) || (dPri == 0 && dSec == 0))
    {
        bPri = 0;
        // if other is Br/Br
        if (Secondary == dSec)
            bSec = 0;
        //if other is Br/Bl
        else if (Primary == dPri)
            bSec = punitvalue % 2;
        //if other is Bl/Bl
        else
            bSec = 1;
    }
    else if ((Primary == 1 && Secondary == 1) || (dPri == 1 && dSec == 1))
    {
        bSec = 1;
        if (dPri == Primary)
            bPri = 1;
        else
            bPri = punitvalue % 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if (punitvalue == 4)
        {
            bPri = 1;
            bSec = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            bPri = 0;
            if (punitvalue % 3 == 0)
                bSec = 0;
            else
                bSec = 1;
        }
    }

    dood baby = new dood(bPri, bSec);

    return baby;
}

void dood::Death()
{

}

void dood::Age()
{
    age = age + 1;
}

int dood::GetPrimary()
{
    return this->Primary;
}

int dood::GetSecondary()
{
    return this->Secondary;
}

int dood::GetAge()
{
    return age;
}
```

dood.h

```
   #pragma once
class dood
{
public:
    dood();
    dood(int, int);
    ~dood();
    void Mutate();
    dood Reproduce(dood);
    void Death();
    void Age();
    int GetPrimary();
    int GetSecondary();
    int GetAge();

private:
    // Genetec Traits "0" for brown, "1" for Blue
    int Primary;
    int Secondary;
    int age=0;
    //Has rand() been seeded?
    static bool init;

};
```

node.cpp

```
#include "node.h"



node::node()
{
}


node::~node()
{
}
```

node.h

```
#pragma once
class node
{
public:
    node();
    ~node();
    node* next;
    dood data;
};
```

I am not using namespace.std anywhere which is the most common issue I see people refer to, and AFAIK node is not predefined anywhere else?  can I get some direction?

Comment: `class dood { public: }` <=== where is the finishing `;` ? Related, I hope this isn't the real code, because `class node` clearly uses `dood`, yet makes no attempts at including the dependent header `dood.h`, at least not in what you posted. Likewise with `Pitri.h` failing to make any attempt at including `node.h` or `dood.h`, both of which contain declarations of dependent items.

Comment: I cut a good portion of the code that should not be relevant as I still need to debug issue further down the line that require this to be fixed first.  I only included the library include from the dude class as it has no relation to the definition of the node class.  Pitri.cpp includes both dood.h and node.h,  shouldn't that be enough as anything further seems redundant?

Comment: Unless the **exact** code as-posted produces the *exact* error you're describing when *we* copy/paste/compile it, we cannot possibly do anything other than guess, and that's not what this site is about. Help us help you.

Comment: Ok, It'll take a second,  to include everything, it's far from complete and I am sure there are many novice mistakes,  I would like to avoid a FULL criticism and just focus on this one error.  ( I originally operated out of namespace std and cut that and additional libraries to troubleshoot this.. I know that's a big no-no.. but that's what college teaches and I gotta follow the process...)

Comment: No one said include *everything*. Include enough so *we* can produce the same problem you have. And if your college teaches you to spam `using namespace std;`, particularly in header files, at least know that on that front you know better than the tenured "prof", because that is a *terrible* practice. Regarding your problem. I strongly suspect the definition of `node` is not available at the time content in Pitri.h is encountered. It is certainly an issue in the posted code thus far.

Comment: Well, everything is there now.  I agree that it seems that Pitri is not recognizing dood or node classes but I don't know if it's my lack of sleep but I was under the reasoning that if you do the include ONCE under the linked list then the includes cascade down to the other includes? Do I need to reorder the includes?  Pitri.cpp includes node.h and dood.h?  I can do the includes in main but I feel I would be missing the true lesson here when I design classes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you WhozCraig, Simple fix of doing my Pitri Class required includes:

```
#include "node.h"
#include "dood.h"
```

in the header file and not the CPP file.

Comment: That's not the only one broken. You still have implicit header dependencies, which is a *bad* practice. Answer forthcoming.